# How to set the IIS File Security to Integrated Windows authentication with a Web Setup Project installer?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, installation

I wrote an ASP.NET web application with an installer.  For the installer, I'm using the *Web Setup Project* under the *Setup and Deployment* project types in Visual Studio 2008.

How do I set the IIS File Security to *Integrated Windows Authentication* on only one .aspx page or directory during the installation process using a *Web Setup Project*?  If it is not possible with the *Web Setup Project* how would I automate that task?

Currently I'm installing the application with the installer and manually setting the security permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the CustomAction Class for the Install Method.

Here's a sample:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/SetIISettings.aspx